# Error when constructing search string for pymongo

Tags: python-3.x, pymongo

I have a query which works when I just type it out

```
    number_of_matches = db[collection_selected].count_documents({'color': {'$regex': 'red', '$options': 'i'}, 'usage': {'$regex': 'build', '$options': 'i'}})
```

Now, I want the ability for users to specify as many search keys and patterns, so I have a function that generates this search string for me.

```
{'color': {'$regex': 'red', '$options': 'i'}, 'usage': {'$regex': 'build', '$options': 'i'}}
```

If I try to use

```
number_of_matches = db[collection_selected].count_documents(search_string)
```

It bombs with this error message
*pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: the match filter must be an expression in an object, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'the match filter must be an expression in an object', 'code': 15959, 'codeName': 'Location15959'}*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[`count_documents`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.count_documents) takes a filter object as the first parameter, so you just need to pass a dictionary not a string:

```
search_dict = {'color': {'$regex': 'red', '$options': 'i'}, 'usage': {'$regex': 'build', '$options': 'i'}}
number_of_matches = db[collection_selected].count_documents(search_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! 

I realized this issue after running find() and it complained about the input having to be a dict. So, I had some initial issues with constructing it, but what you suggested worked perfectly.